# SpringXD counter not working with Kafka source

Tags: analytics, counter, apache-kafka, spring-xd

I am using SpringXD 1.3 and Apache Kafka 0.9.0.0.

I have a functioning Kafka producer that I was able to configure as a Kafka source in Spring XD (I use a Groovy script to transform the message before logging it).

```
stream create --name metrics1 --definition "kafka --topic=metrics | transform --script=MetricsInterpreter.groovy | log" --deploy
```

I can see my Kafka messages getting printed in Spring XD logs. So this stream is working as intended.

However, the counter I create doesn't show up in the list of counters.

```
stream create --name metrics1tap1 --definition "tap:stream:metrics1 > counter --name=hitcount" --deploy
```

Although I get a success message (`Created and deployed new stream 'metrics1tap1'`), this counter does not show up when I try to list counters using "counter list" command.

I tried the TwitterSearch counter example from documentation and that worked fine.

Question: Is there a configuration/setup step that I am missing? Why would my own counter not work in this case?

(FYI both Kafka and SpringXD are running in dev/single-node mode)

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm the `counter list` will only display the specific counter if at least one value in the counter.

Are you sure you have at least one message that is possibly received by the counter?

Also, when you do `stream list` do you see the stream `metrics1tap1` in there?